# Xamarin.android Open Autocomplete Dropdown Upwards

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, autocompletetextview

I have an autocomplete dropdown that opens down and not only overlaps the textfield, but also goes behind the keyboard. I need the dropdown to account for the textfield and keyboard when opening and instead of opening down into the keyboard and over the textfield. The user is unable to see what they are typing as the suggestions overlap the textfield. Below is my code

the layout that contains the autocomplete is selectionList.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <RelativeLayout
        p1:orientation="horizontal"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:id="@+id/mainLayout2"
        p1:background="@drawable/border_full_white_black"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="52dp"
        p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        p1:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        p1:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
        <TextView
            p1:layout_width="100dp"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/label"
            p1:textColor="#47463f"
            p1:gravity="center"
            p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            p1:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <TextView xmlns:p2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            p1:layout_width="20dp"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:id="@+id/required_label"
            p1:text="*"
            p1:textColor="#F0b323"
            p1:gravity="center"
            p1:textSize="20dp"
            p1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            p1:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        <EditText xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:id="@+id/manual_edittext"
            p1:gravity="center"
            p1:textColor="#47463f"
            p1:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            p1:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            p1:background="@drawable/backgroundstyle"
            tools:visibility="invisible"
            p1:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/required_label"
            p1:layout_toEndOf="@+id/user_label" />
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            p1:id="@+id/autoComplete"
            p1:visibility="invisible"
            p1:gravity="center"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            p1:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            p1:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            p1:singleLine="true"
            p1:imeOptions="actionDone"
            p1:popupBackground="#ffffff"
            p1:maxLength="2"
            p1:dropDownAnchor="@+id/autoComplete"
            p1:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
            p1:background="@drawable/border_bottom_lightgray_white"
            p1:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/required_label"
            p1:layout_toEndOf="@+id/label" 
            p1:textColor="#47463f"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The autocomplete layout resource file is autocomplete_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
p1:background="@android:color/white"
p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
p1:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView
    p1:text="Medium Text"
     p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     p1:layout_width="match_parent"
     p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
     p1:id="@+id/textView1"
     p1:textColor="#ff000000"
     p1:gravity="center"
     p1:paddingBottom="8dip"
     p1:paddingTop="8dip"
     p1:background="@drawable/border_bottom_lightgray_white"
     p1:textSize="15dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

the code to set the adapter is:

```
   var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.autocomplete_layout, Resource.Id.textView1, list);
```

currently the dropdown overlaps as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your description and your code, I guess that you want to create Auto Complete for Xamarin.Android, if yes, you can take a look the following code.

Firstly, create `list_item.xml` and save it inside the Resources/Layout folder, will be used for each item that appears in the list of suggestions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="#000">
</TextView>
```

Then the content view is set to the main.xml layout.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string[] countries = new String[] {
"Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","American Samoa","Andorra",   
"Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Wallis and Futuna","Western Sahara",
"Yemen","Yugoslavia","Zambia","Zimbabwe"
};
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        AutoCompleteTextView textView = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autocomplete_country);
        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Layout.list_item, countries);

        textView.Adapter = adapter;
    }
  
}
```

The Main.xaml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Country" />
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
```

More detailed info, you can take a look:

[Auto Complete for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/auto-complete)

The Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I already have the autocomplete setup but need it to open upwards as i have a list of dropdown and the ones on the bottom of the screen seem to have the dropdown open down which overlaps the keyboard and the input field. I don't want it to wrap over the keyboard. Instead it should open open upwards and not overlap with the search text or the keyboard.

Comment: @z123 Can you provide one simple sample at gtihub, I will download your sample to test, it is helpful to understand your problem.